# URL rewriting with datefolder

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a URL that looks like:

```
example.com/upload/2018/01/11/ABCDE.jpg
example.com/upload/2018/01/10/BCDEF.jpg
example.com/upload/2017/02/11/12345.jpg
```

The file name are unique between all folder, how would I go about converting that URL to access above url:

```
example.com/upload/ABCDE.jpg
example.com/upload/BCDEF.jpg
example.com/upload/12345.jpg
```

After using htaccess, when user entering

```
example.com/upload/ABCDE.jpg
```

Rewrite to my route.php to get the original URL from database first

```
example.com/upload/route.php?i=ABCDE.jpg
```

When rewrite to `route.php`, the URL still not changed, but after the `route.php` got the original URL and redirect it using PHP header, the URL was changed, any solution to prevent the URL change?

Here .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /upload/

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.jpe?g)$ route.php?i=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Route.php to get the original URL from database

```
<?php
   /* some sql selection */
   header("Location: $url"); // redirect to original URL <-- this will change the URL, but i want to prevent it.
?>
```

Comment: @anubhava no, i want to enter `example.com/upload/ABCDE.jpg` to access `example.com/upload/2018/01/11/ABCDE.jpg`, in my case the folder name based on year, month and day, so i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: How about using database to save the `yyyy/mm/dd` url, when access `example.com/upload/ABCDE.jpg`, it rewrite to `example.com/upload/route.php?i=ABCDE.jpg`, then get the `yyyy/mm/dd` url from database and access it.

Comment: @anubhava Does this idea have high workload of the server? my website have high traffic, in this case, when everyone access the url, it need select the database to get the url.

Comment: Workload can be reduced by caching this mapping since this mapping is not going to change frequently.

Comment: After using this idea, the url will be changed after get the original url from database, but i want to redirect it without changing url, any solution? like imgur.com

Comment: My solution below doesn't change URL in browser.

Comment: Yes, when rewrite to route.php, then select db to find the URL and redirect it, does this will change URL in browser?

Comment: when using PHP header to redirect to datefolder, the URL was changed.

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question with the URL that is causing redirect and finally redirected URL.

Comment: @anubhava updated, the .htaccess is find, it not changing the URL when rewrite to `route.php`, but after get the original URL from db in `route.php` and using header to redirect it, the URL was changed, i want to prevent it.

Comment: Your use of `header` function is the problem because `header` sends raw HTTP header back to browser and browser attempts to load the new URL. You must use `include` function instead of `header`. [See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173740/what-is-difference-between-header-and-include-where-which-one-should-be-used)

Answer (score 1):

For rewriting to `example.com/upload/route.php?i=ABCDE.jpg`, create a new .htaccess inside `/upload/` directory with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /upload/

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.jpe?g)$ route.php?i=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```